# Android: Invocation Target Exception while creating OptionsMenu

Tags: android, android-xml, android-optionsmenu

I am Implementing `OptionsMenu` and the items are read from the xml file in the menu folder of the project i.e `res/menu/menu.xml`. After Overriding the `OnCreateOptionsMenu` method and  `onOptionsItemSelected` , i am receiving the `Invocation Target Exception`. Here are the methods:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

**ItemSelected Methods**

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
             switch (item.getItemId())
             {
             case R.id.menu_bookmark:
                 // Single menu item is selected do something
                 // Ex: launching new activity/screen or show alert message
                 Toast.makeText(FullscreenActivity.this, "Bookmark is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 return true;

             case R.id.menu_save:
                 Toast.makeText(FullscreenActivity.this, "Save is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 return true;

             case R.id.menu_search:
                 Toast.makeText(FullscreenActivity.this, "Search is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 return true;

             case R.id.menu_share:
                 Toast.makeText(FullscreenActivity.this, "Share is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 return true;

             case R.id.menu_delete:
                 Toast.makeText(FullscreenActivity.this, "Delete is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 return true;

             case R.id.menu_preferences:
                 Toast.makeText(FullscreenActivity.this, "Preferences is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 return true;

             default:
                 return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
             }

    }
```

Here is the **menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_bookmark"
          android:title="Bookmark" />

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_save"
          android:title="Save" />

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
          android:title="Search" />

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_share"
          android:title="Share" />

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_delete"
          android:title="Delete" /> 

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_preferences"
          android:title="Preferences" />
</menu>
```

**Logcat**

```
        06-21 12:23:42.875: I/ActivityManager(89): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.app.wabicountermanager/.FullscreenActivity} from pid 2436
06-21 12:23:43.125: I/ActivityManager(89): Start proc com.app.wabicountermanager for activity com.app.wabicountermanager/.FullscreenActivity: pid=2446 uid=10040 gids={3003}
06-21 12:23:45.815: E/AndroidRuntime(2446): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.wabicountermanager/com.app.wabicountermanager.FullscreenActivity}: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
06-21 12:23:45.815: E/AndroidRuntime(2446):     at com.app.wabicountermanager.FullscreenActivity.onCreate(FullscreenActivity.java:73)
06-21 12:23:46.205: W/ActivityManager(89):   Force finishing activity com.app.wabicountermanager/.FullscreenActivity
06-21 12:23:46.725: W/ActivityManager(89): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{410643e8 com.app.wabicountermanager/.FullscreenActivity}
06-21 12:23:57.166: W/ActivityManager(89): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{410643e8 com.app.wabicountermanager/.FullscreenActivity}
```

**Exception details**

```
WabiCounterManager [Android Application]    
WabiCounterManager [Android Application]    
    DalvikVM[localhost:8652]    
        Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
            ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1956    
            ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1981 
            ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 123    
            ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1147  
            ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
            Looper.loop() line: 137 
            ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4424    
            Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
            Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511  
            ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 784  
            ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 551 
            NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]  
        Thread [<10> Binder Thread #2] (Running)    
        Thread [<9> Binder Thread #1] (Running) 
        Daemon Thread [<8> FinalizerWatchdogDaemon] (Running)   
        Daemon Thread [<7> FinalizerDaemon] (Running)
```

I did'nt get what i am missing. Thanks

Comment: post your complete log

Comment: Let me, just wait a minute.

Comment: Check my edit, this is what all it is showing when app is launched and throws the exception.

Comment: Please add the stacktrace of your exception...it'll help locate the problem. I copied your code and it runs fine for me.

Comment: @JibranKhan i guess you have attached a debugger which might be creating problems. Still just post the entire stacktrace to help you out.

Comment: @SeanSWatkins, check my edit. I guess this is what you want to see ?

Comment: Just a suggestion, don't return true -- return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)) instead

Comment: @CRUSADER, you mean after the case is executed ?

Comment: I'm assuming your onCreate method and all the other stuff is correct? Also what device are you running your code on? It runs fine on my S4

Comment: yes when i comment the entire options menu code, it works correctly. I am testing the code on emulator as well as S2 plus(Jelly bean).

Comment: Are you using SherlockActionBar? If so then you should call `getSupportMenuInflater()`.

Comment: No i am not, it is not using sherlock acvtion bar.

Comment: @JibranKhan in your `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` your return statement should be return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu))

Comment: @CRUSADER, that did'nt work :(

Comment: Check my edit, i have posted the entire LOGCAT from starting to the exception of the application.

Comment: @JibranKhan I wasnt answering your question but suggesting you good coding practise...

Comment: @JibranKhan you have posted trace of all the processes on your device...
just use filter to display messages relating to your app!!!!

Comment: if you are using a debugger, just stop the debugger. And post the exact exception you see in the logcat when the app crashes. it'll look like 06-21 12:12:31.386: E/ERROR ...etc. That's what we are looking for

Comment: @7bluephoenix, now it is only showing the related app stack trace. Please check the Edit.

Comment: @SeanSWatkins, I have removed the debugger and the error is showing, please check the edit in LogCat section.

Comment: still not seeing the actual crash. if you are using the Logcat function of DDMS then it should be colour coded. It'll be all read and rather long. Something like this `06-21 09:29:34.801: E/AndroidRuntime(26434): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-21 09:29:34.801: E/AndroidRuntime(26434): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.diginex.SOTest/com.diginex.SOTest.MyActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "o"`   Just Longer

Comment: Oh it worked, cleaning the project did the job. I am very thankfull to all of you guys for helping me.

Comment: LOL!!! I thought about that, dang it. lol. Oh well glad it's working :-)

Comment: LOL! There was one more issue which was not occuring when i was running the app without OptionsMenu, that was i added the openOptionsMenu(); in onCreate() methode of the activity. Removing that and cleaning the project did the job i guess.